# How to concat 2 or more sqlalchemy rowproxy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables with same structure but in different db instance & schema.
So I run 2 queries:

```
rows1 = conn1.execute(query1)
rows2 = conn2.execute(query2)
```

is there any magic to concat/combine these 2 result?(rows1 & row2)

is it possible like list:
`rows = rows1 + rows2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries over different databases cannot be UNIONed, so any solution must be in the application layer.

The simplest solution is to materialise both resultsets as lists and combine them:

```py
combined_rows = list(rows1) + list(rows2)
for row in combined_rows:
    # do stuff with row
```

If materialising the lists is not desirable you could use [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```py
for row in itertools.chain(rows1, rows2):
    # do stuff with row
```